# Finding the Highest number of two lists-haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

merge xs     []     = xs

merge []     ys     = ys

merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys

maxOfTwoLists  [x] [y]  = maximum (merge [x] [y])
```

I am trying to combine the two lists then find the max value in the single list. It compiles but when i call `maxOfTwoLists` it gives me a non-exhaustive patterns error. My merge returns a single list just fine, and maximum takes a single list. So it feels like it should be working.

Comment: Your `maxOfTwoLists` pattern matches on two lists of one element each

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. How do i make it match on an entire list?

Comment: Remove the square brackets (both on the arguments and in the function body)

Answer (score 1):

As @badcook notes the pattern match isn't quite right.

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys

maxOfTwoLists :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
maxOfTwoLists [] ys = maximum ys
maxOfTwoLists xs [] = maximum xs
maxOfTwoLists xs ys = maximum (merge xs ys)
```

I'll guess you wrote the `merge` function as an exercise but you can also use `++` from `Prelude` to append one list to another.

```
maxOfTwoLists :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
maxOfTwoLists xs ys = maximum (xs ++ ys)
```

Output:

```
λ> maxOfTwoLists [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
6
λ> maxOfTwoLists [1,2,3] []
3
λ> maxOfTwoLists [] [1,2,3]
3
λ>
```

Comment: If you're going to use `++`, don't bother with the patterns for the `[]` cases. Just the third case is plenty on its own.

Comment: The same holds when using `merge`: there's no need to handle empty lists since `merge` is handling those. (Of course, if both lists are empty, `maximum` will still raise an exception)

Comment: i knew this was a solution! Im just a newbie to haskell. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to merge two lists, the builtin `concat` would help. It flattens a list, so we could do the following:

```
maxOfTwoLists :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
maxOfTwoLists xs ys = maximum $ concat [xs,ys]
```

In which, `$` means to evaluate the result of the right side function before applying it to the left side function.

Comment: that $ sign will be usefull later on as well. Thank you very much.